# How many ways can I choose 3 cards so that the numbers on the 3 cards is a multiple of 6 without numbers repeating?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have $6$ cards, numbered from $0$ to $5$. How many ways can I choose 3 cards so that the numbers on the $3$ cards is a multiple of $6$ without numbers repeating?

How can I use permutation or combination to find this?

I got $19$ ways by doing the long process as such:

$120, 132, 150,$
$204, 210, 234, 240,$
$312, 324, 342, 354,$
$402, 420, 432, 450,$
$504, 510, 534, 540$

Answer (score 1):

In order to be divisible by $6$, the number must be divisible by both $2$ and $3$.  It's divisible by $2$ if and only if the last digit is $0,2\text{ or }4$.  A number in base $10$ is divisible by $3$ if and only if the sum of the digits is divisible by $3$.

So, if it end in $0$, the other two digits can be $1,2$, $1,5$, $2,4$, or $4,5$.  Each of these gives 2 possibilities, since we can arrange the first two digits in either order.  So, there are $8$ case when the last digit is $0$.

I leave the other two cases to you.

Comment: get it.thank you

Comment: You should either place the pairs of numbers in sets or use semicolons to separate them.